# how would i go about getting mouse coordinates

Tags: windows

my question is pretty simple. i just need to get my mouses coordinates, i really didn't want to use any programs but if i have to then i will. i need my coordinates for a program I'm writing,
*someone please help*. I've also tried googling it but couldn't find any answers.
also i even tried coding a program to find my coordinates, i used code i found online and that was erroring so i tried fixing it and it didn't work. so if you could just tell me a shortcut or something that could show me my mouse coordinates.
**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ use [GetCursorPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos) api it will give you x and y of the mouse example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    POINT coords;
    GetCursorPos(&coords);
    std::cout << "X: " << coords.x << " Y: " << coords.y << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: didnt work for me

Comment: Sorry its not GetMousePos its GetCursorPos @SnoDev

Comment: im currently in visual studio,

Comment: im getting POINT is not defined

Comment: include Windows Header: #include <Windows.h>

Comment: to make it easier i will add full code example @SnoDev